# Response.Write Call jQuery dialog box in c# code-behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I want to Call jQuery dialog box in c# Code-behind using `Response.Write` Method. I tried using `RegisterScriptBlock`

```
Response.Write("<script> $(document).ready(function () {$('#divOutputWindow').html('You are not authorised to view this Page..!!').dialog({title: 'Notice...',show: 'slide',hide: 'blind',modal: true,buttons: {'Ok':function(){window.location = 'Default.aspx';}}});});</script>");
```

All My jQuery are properly included, as i am able to call dialog box from my JS file. ID : `divOutputWindow` is present on .aspx page

still not able to see jQuery dialog box.

**P.S. : My .aspx page does not contain `<form>` tag Hence `RegisterScriptBlock` wont work**

Comment: @RandomWebGuy But User must get a message that why he has been redirected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Worked..!!

Added `<form id="frmUserManagement" runat="server">` in my aspx page

and in Code-behind

```
StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
strScript.Append("$(document).ready(function(){");
strScript.Append("$('#divOutputWindow').html('You are not authorised to view this Page..!!<br/>Redirecting to Default Page.').dialog({title: 'Error...',show: 'slide',hide: 'blind',modal: true,buttons: {'Ok': function () {window.location='Default.aspx';}}});");
strScript.Append("});");
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(frmUserManagement, frmUserManagement.GetType(), "Script", strScript.ToString(), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

It didn't work because Response.Write adds the code block at the top of the page. In this way the script is executed before that jq library is loaded.
You need to use ScriptManager and RegisterClientScriptBlock.

Comment: you are right..!! my `script` tag gets loaded just below `head` tag before all jQuery lib. how can i achieve the same using `RegisterClientScriptBlock` ? Can you post ?

Comment: Sorry but I've worked but I see that you have found the solution :)